При установке repo sync -c -j8 возникла в конце такая ошибка: error: Checking out local projects failed. ? как можно исправить эту ошибку?
error: Unable to fully sync the tree
error: Checking out local projects failed.
Failing repos:
packages/modules/Virtualization
Try re-running with "-j1 --fail-fast" to exit at the first error.
================================================================================
Repo command failed due to the following `SyncError` errors:
platform/packages/modules/Virtualization checkout d9d063acae4fb98d7a88e12baf8b1ea80b797eb2

При установке repo sync -c -j8 в конце выдала эту ошибку, говорит что надо заново запустить -j1 --fail-fast так же очень долго будет устанавливаться... и так 5 часов этот процесс выполнялся
подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить... Спасибо
